# How do you import the command mysqlx into my React App?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, mysql-connector, mysql-8.0

I'm trying to import the command mysqlx into my React App.

I tried a couple of different methods but it does not recognize the command mysqlx in the console. It seems I can't call it without importing it into the app.  I'm pretty new at this so it may be something easy. This is all on a local windows machine.

```
import mysqlx from '@mysql/xdevapi'
```

After I tried to run the app. See error below.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/lib/Protocol/Util/systemAttributes.js:101
   98 | }
   99 | 
  100 | const clientAttributes = {
> 101 |   _pid: process.pid.toString(),
  102 |   _platform: platformName(),
  103 |   _os: osName(),
  104 |   _source_host: sourceHostName(),
View compiled
./node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/lib/Protocol/Util/systemAttributes.js
http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:44169:30
__webpack_require__
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/webpack/bootstrap:785
  782 | };
  783 | 
  784 | // Execute the module function
> 785 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  786 | 
  787 | // Flag the module as loaded
  788 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
▼ 2 stack frames were expanded.
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/lib/Protocol/Client.js:68
./node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/lib/Protocol/Client.js
http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:22283:30
▲ 2 stack frames were expanded.
__webpack_require__
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/webpack/bootstrap:785
  782 | };
  783 | 
  784 | // Execute the module function
> 785 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  786 | 
  787 | // Flag the module as loaded
  788 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
./node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/lib/DevAPI/Session.js
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/lib/DevAPI/Session.js:32
__webpack_require__
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/webpack/bootstrap:785
  782 | };
  783 | 
  784 | // Execute the module function
> 785 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  786 | 
  787 | // Flag the module as loaded
  788 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
./node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/lib/DevAPI/ConnectionPool.js
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/lib/DevAPI/ConnectionPool.js:32
__webpack_require__
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/webpack/bootstrap:785
  782 | };
  783 | 
  784 | // Execute the module function
> 785 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  786 | 
  787 | // Flag the module as loaded
  788 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
./node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/lib/DevAPI/Client.js
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/lib/DevAPI/Client.js:32
__webpack_require__
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/webpack/bootstrap:785
  782 | };
  783 | 
  784 | // Execute the module function
> 785 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  786 | 
  787 | // Flag the module as loaded
  788 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
./node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/index.js
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/index.js:36
__webpack_require__
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/webpack/bootstrap:785
  782 | };
  783 | 
  784 | // Execute the module function
> 785 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  786 | 
  787 | // Flag the module as loaded
  788 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
Module../src/App.js
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:91:72
__webpack_require__
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/webpack/bootstrap:785
  782 | };
  783 | 
  784 | // Execute the module function
> 785 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  786 | 
  787 | // Flag the module as loaded
  788 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
Module../src/index.js
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:220:62
__webpack_require__
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/webpack/bootstrap:785
  782 | };
  783 | 
  784 | // Execute the module function
> 785 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  786 | 
  787 | // Flag the module as loaded
  788 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
0
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:359:18
__webpack_require__
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/webpack/bootstrap:785
  782 | };
  783 | 
  784 | // Execute the module function
> 785 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  786 | 
  787 | // Flag the module as loaded
  788 | module.l = true;
View compiled
checkDeferredModules
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/webpack/bootstrap:45
  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 | 
View compiled
Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push]
C:/Users/brian/OneDrive/Desktop/nms-appV4/nms-app/webpack/bootstrap:32
  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;
View compiled
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:67
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.
```

Comment: Can you include the code where the error is occurring? `systemAttributes.js` around line 101. Edit, I see that's from node_modules. What's in your package.json?

Comment: This is what I pull when I goto that file

`const clientAttributes = {
    _pid: process.pid.toString(),
    _platform: platformName(),
    _os: osName(),
    _source_host: sourceHostName(),
    _client_name: 'mysql-connector-nodejs',
    _client_version: pkg.version,
    _client_license: pkg.license
};

module.exports = function () {
    return clientAttributes;
};`

Comment: In my package Json Folder

`{
  "name": "nms-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@mysql/xdevapi": "^8.0.18",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-popper": "^1.3.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.1.1",
    "typescript": "^3.6.4"
  }`

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much info presented here, but based on your error:

`process.pid` is undefined. You have to figure out why that is undefined. There are similar questions:

[Node console.log(process.pid) prints undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50876667/node-console-logprocess-pid-prints-undefined)

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, I searched the entire folder for the word electron and it only had a yarn module called electron to chromium plug in.  I did use a npm package to change my yarn.lock file to a Json file after using npx create-react-app.  And then plugged in all the dependencies as listed above.  Then tried to import  the mysqlx into the app to write Components to connect to a MYSQL Database. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand if this is something running with Electron or a plain browser web app, in any case, you don't seem to be running Node.js, but some other JS environment which does have the `process` API. If it's Electron, then using `node` as the `target`, as described in the answer linked by the first answer, should do the trick. If it's a plain browser web app, it won't work.

Comment: Do you have a step by step process to add functions from the @mysql/xdevapi to a React developed app/website?

Comment: It has nothing to do with React. The underlying driver code uses the Node.js TCP/TLS socket API to talk to a MySQL server, so it does not work in a browser, unless there is some kind of a shim for based on websockets or some other network-level browser API. I have no idea, since I'm not really into frontend stuff, but who knows. In any case, the driver is meant to work with the Node.js engine, not any JavaScript environment.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I used express to create a new route and was able to get the database connected via route.use() function.

For a follow up question please visit:

[How to connect my route parameter in express with @mysql/x devAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59019784/how-to-connect-my-route-parameter-in-express-with-mysql-x-devapi)