# How to connect my route parameter in express with @mysql/x devAPI?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, mysql-8.0

Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysqlx = require('@mysql/xdevapi');




router.use(`/:email`, function (req, res, next){
    mysqlx.getSession( {

        user: 'username', 
        password: 'password',
        host: 'localhost', 
        port: '33060' } )

        // .then(session => {
        //   console.log(session.inspect());
        // })

        .then(function (session) {
            var db = session.getSchema('nms2019local');
            var opsTable = db.getTable('operators');
            return opsTable
                .select (['email', 'admin'])
                .where('email like :email')
                .bind('email',':email')
                .execute (function (row) {
                    console.log(row);

                });    
        })
        .then(function (myResult){
            console.log(myResult);

        })
        .catch(function (err){
            console.log(err);
        })

        next()


    });


    router.use('/', function (req, res,){

        res.send('DB Is Connected');

    });

    module.exports = router;
```

}

Through postman I run the following GET command:

get /expressroutename/email/test@email.com I get the following in nodemon:

```
GET /expressroutename/email/test@email.com 200 36.096 ms - 15
{
  getWarnings: [Function: getWarnings],
  getWarningsCount: [Function: getWarningsCount],
  fetchAll: [Function: fetchAll],
  fetchOne: [Function: fetchOne],
  getColumns: [Function: getColumns],
  getResults: [Function: getResults],
  nextResult: [Function: nextResult],
  toArray: [Function: toArray]
}
```

when I column out the .where command

```
 //.where('email like :email')
```

and put in the following in Postman I get in nodemon:

```
GET /expressroutename/email 200 45.116 ms - 15
[ 'test@email.com', 1 ]
[ 'test1@email.com', 1 ]
{
  getWarnings: [Function: getWarnings],
  getWarningsCount: [Function: getWarningsCount],
  fetchAll: [Function: fetchAll],
  fetchOne: [Function: fetchOne],
  getColumns: [Function: getColumns],
  getResults: [Function: getResults],
  nextResult: [Function: nextResult],
  toArray: [Function: toArray]
```

I think its a syntax error, but I have typed it via the docs many times and it doesn't seem to work. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it might be an issue with the way you are using `bind()`.

Basically you are providing a filtering criteria `'email like :email'` where `:email` is a placeholder that is supposed to be replaced by a specific value using `bind()`. However, you are assigning `':email'` (the specific `String` value) to the placeholder, and I suspect you don't have any row in that `operators` table where `email = ':email'`. That's why when you remove the filtering criteria (specified by the `where()` API) you start getting proper results, since the filter isn't actually being applied anymore.

So, if you want to filter, what you need to do is provide the actual email address as the second parameter of `bind()`. I'm a bit rusty with Express, but I think the following should do the trick:

```
opsTable.select(['email', 'admin'])
  .where('email like :email')
  .bind('email', req.params.email)
```

Note that the first parameter of `bind()` is the name of the placeholder without the `:` (colon) prefix.

Disclaimer: I'm the lead dev of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js

Comment: YES, this was perfect slight modification is I had to create a constant:
const email = req.params.email 

then in the bind line:

.bind('email', email)  
(no quotes), I will put in the final answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysqlx = require('@mysql/xdevapi');




router.use(`email/:email`, function (req, res, next){
         const email = req.params.email        

     mysqlx.getSession( {

        user: 'username', 
        password: 'password',
        host: 'localhost', 
        port: '33060' } )

        // .then(session => {
        //   console.log(session.inspect());
        // })

        .then(function (session) {
            var db = session.getSchema('dbname');
            var TestTable = db.getTable('test');
            return TestTable
                .select (['email', 'admin'])
                .where('email like :email')
                .bind('email', email)
                .execute (function (row) {
                    console.log(row);

                });    
        })
        .then(function (myResult){
            console.log(myResult);

        })
        .catch(function (err){
            console.log(err);
        })

        next()


    });


    router.use('/', function (req, res,){

        res.send('DB Is Connected');

    });

    module.exports = router;
```